# Storing array in hidden input, and using ajax to print out

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to store an array in the value of an element, and then use ajax to print the array, but when I tried to print the array, using print_r(), instead of printing the array, it printed the word array. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$array[0] = 0;
$array[1] = 1;
$array[2] = 2;

echo "<input id = 'array' type = 'hidden' value = '$array'>";
//more codes

?>
```

**In JavaScript:**

```
var array = $("#"+array).val();
//more codes
data: { array: array },
```

**On Second Page**

```
array = $_POST['array'];
print_r(array);
```

**Result**

```
array
```

**Expected Result**

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: `var array = $("#"+array).val();` ==> `var array = $("#array").val();`

Comment: you can use `json_encode` while outputting the value on the `input` field and on next page before using the value use `json_decode`. 

You can also use `serialize` and `unserialize` to achieve the same effect

Comment: Why are you doing this anyway? PHP session variables may be a better way if you're just passing data between pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your array to json before using it on JavaScript

```
echo "<input id = 'array' type = 'hidden' value = '" . json_encode($array) . "'>";
```

And decode it on the second page:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
print_r(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript and php have different syntax to use with array.

you should use

`echo "<input id = 'array' type = 'hidden' value = '". implode(',', $array) ."'>";`

...

On Second Page

`$array = $_POST['array'];
array = explode(',', $array);
print_r(array);`